# Batch Scripting command line closes after i enter a number

Tags: batch-file, scripting

In the code below i ask a user to type a number to enter that folder but everytime i type a number and press enter command line closes right away.

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET VARCOUNT=0

for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b c:\users\') do (
  set /a VARCOUNT+=1
  set profvar!VARCOUNT!=%%f)

echo --------------------------------------
for /l %%v IN (1,1,!VARCOUNT!) do (
  echo     %%v - !profvar%%v!
)
echo --------------------------------------

set /p SELPROF=Enter the number of the profile to copy: 

echo Selected profile = !profvar%SELPROF%!
```

any ideas on what is wrong.

Comment: You probably started your scipt with a doubleclick.  So when it finishes, the window closes. There is nothing in your script to prevent the code from finishing (like a `pause` command).

Comment: You generally should start your scripts from an already open command window (especially for troubleshooting), so the window will not close at the end of the script or when any severe syntax error occurs. Then you can read any error messages which will help you to improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, if you execute a batch file by double clicking on it from Windows File Explorer, the default behavior is to execute and close.  If you want it to stop, you will need to add a `pause` at the end. This will result in the following:

[image]

And here is the amended code:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET VARCOUNT=0

for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b c:\users\') do (
  set /a VARCOUNT+=1
  set profvar!VARCOUNT!=%%f)

echo --------------------------------------
for /l %%v IN (1,1,!VARCOUNT!) do (
  echo     %%v - !profvar%%v!
)
echo --------------------------------------

set /p SELPROF=Enter the number of the profile to copy: 

echo Selected profile = !profvar%SELPROF%!

pause
```